# jQuery - Change form action based on resolution

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple form and I need to post values to 2 different pages. one is for desktop and the other one is mobile.

Basically :
if resolution is higher then 768px, send form to desktop.php
if resolution is lower then 768px, send form to mobile.php

Is there any way to do it with jQuery?

Comment: A *single* form page should be able to adapt to the resolution changes *using styling alone*. That is the aim of responsive design. You do not need different pages. e.g. Q: What happens if someone resizes a desktop browser to under 768px?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of check the client resolution, i think the best to do is ckeck if your client is using a mobile device, because if someone resizes a desktop browser to under 768px you may have some problems.

With jquery you can use the `submit` event:

```
$('#your_form').submit( function () {
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        $(this).attr('action', 'mobile.php');
    }
})
```